# convert the three columns data in to single column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with n columns

```
col1     col2       col3
----------------------
val
val
NaN
val
val
        val1
        val1
        NaN
        val1
        val1
                   val2
                   val2
                   NaN
                   val2
                   val2
```

and i want to convert the n columns into single column as:

### o/p:

```
col4 
-----
val
val
NaN
val
val
val1
val1
NaN
val1
val1                           
val2
val2
NaN
val2
val2
```

i am getting the each column data and when i am  assigning the data it is overwriting the data.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
     col = df[i]
     df1['A']=df[col]
```

But it overwriting the previously written data.So if i want data not to be overwritten and add n columns data to single column using pandas

Comment: Are the empty values `nans` or empty strings `''`?

Comment: @Tabbakhh But i dont know the column names thats y i am looping through the columns.

Comment: @MohitMotwani empty values are nans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in the comment that the blank is NaNs, so you just need `T` and `bfill`

```
df2.T.bfill().iloc[0]

Out[141]:
0      val
1      val
2      NaN
3      val
4      val
5     val1
6     val1
7      NaN
8     val1
9     val1
10    val2
11    val2
12     NaN
13    val2
14    val2
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

---

**Note**: Originally, I filled the whole `df` for just in case, so I used both `ffill` and `bfill`. If you don't need it, you may use either `ffill` or `bfill` with different `iloc`

```
df2.T.ffill().iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a simple sum over the rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,], 'col2': 
[np.NaN,2,np.NaN,np.NaN,], 'col3': [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,np.NaN,]})
df


    col1    col2    col3
0   1.0      NaN     NaN
1   NaN      2.0     NaN
2   NaN      NaN     3.0
3   NaN      NaN     NaN
```

and now you can just sum over the rows (by using axis = 1) and we want the sum of NaNs to be NaN so we use min_count = 1:

```
%%timeit
df['col4'] = df.sum(axis=1,min_count=1)

Out: 1000 loops, best of 3: 334 µs per loop

%%timeit
df.T.bfill().iloc[0]

Out: 1000 loops, best of 3: 524 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the least efficient way to do it, but it should get the job done:

```
combined_col = [] 
     for i in range(len(df)): 
         col = df.iloc[i, :] 
         if col.isnull().sum() == len(df.columns): 
             combined_col.append(np.NAN) 
         else: 
             combined_col.append(col[~col.isnull()][0]) 

df['combined_col'] = combined_col
```

Results:

```
    col1  col2  col3  combined_col
0    1.0   NaN   NaN   1.0
1    2.0   NaN   NaN   2.0
2    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    3.0   NaN   NaN   3.0
4    4.0   NaN   NaN   4.0
5    NaN   7.0   NaN   7.0
6    NaN  13.0   NaN  13.0
7    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
8    NaN  22.0   NaN  22.0
9    NaN  16.0   NaN  16.0
10   NaN   NaN  12.0  12.0
11   NaN   NaN  32.0  32.0
12   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
13   NaN   NaN   1.0   1.0
14   NaN   NaN   6.0   6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert empty strings to `NaN's` using [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and then use [`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) as:

```
df = df.replace({' ':np.nan}).ffill(1)['col3'].to_frame(name='col4')

print(df)
    col4
0    val
1    val
2    NaN
3    val
4    val
5   val1
6   val1
7    NaN
8   val1
9   val1
10  val2
11  val2
12   NaN
13  val2
14  val2
```