# Propagate values from multiple columns to a single column - Pandas

Tags: pandas

```
 col1   col2    col3   combined
----------------------------
val1                   val1
val1                   val1
NaN                    val1
val1                   val1
       val2            val2
       NaN             val2
       val2            val2
              val3     val3
              NaN      val3
              val3     val3 

output:
-------
col1   col2    col3   combined
----------------------------
val1                   val1
val1                   val1
NaN                    NaN
val1                   val1
       val2            val2
       NaN             NaN
       val2            val2
              val3     val3
              NaN      NaN
              val3     val3
```

I have columns and i have to check if in any NaN value  is present in one column same has to updated in the combined column eventhough value is present using pandas.

```
i am using the follwing code:
cols = df[0:len(df.columns)-1]
for col in cols:
    print (col)
    df.combined = df.combined.fillna(value=df[col])
```

but the value is not getting changed.

```
df.T.bfill().iloc[-1]
```

if i am using bfill it is filling the values eventhough NaN is present.

Comment: `df.combined.fillna(value=df[col])` this means you are filling the nan values of the combined column with values from `df[col]`. That is why its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert the three columns data in to single column using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948388/convert-the-three-columns-data-in-to-single-column-using-pandas)

Comment: @MohitMotwani Its not a duplicate. the one you linked and this one are different questions

Comment: there is `space` in column and `NaN` in column ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.where` with `isna` and `sum`

```
# Change 1 to 3 if the blank space is None or NaN thanks to @Mohit Motwani
df['combined'] = np.where(df.isna().sum(axis=1) >= 1, np.nan, df.combined)

df
Out[34]: 
   col1  col2  col3 combined
0  val1                 val1
1  val1                 val1
2   NaN                  NaN
3  val1                 val1
4        val2           val2
5         NaN            NaN
6        val2           val2
7              val3     val3
8               NaN      NaN
9              val3     val3
```

Comment: I've made the change from 1 to 3, because that is the right condition to check.

Comment: @MohitMotwani Why 3? What if a blank space is just string?

Comment: hmm. good question. I'm assuming, the blank space is null. Can confirm with the OP? If all blanks are null, your previous code didn't work. But this won't work if they are empty strings.

Comment: @MohitMotwani I think it is string based on `NaN` in columns maybe we have to confirm this with the OP

Answer (score 0):

I iterate over rows and use `isna()` to find NaNs and assign corresponding indices to NaN in the "combined" column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

### Generate sample data
arr = np.zeros((9,3))
comb = np.zeros(9)
for i in range(3):
    val = np.random.randint(-5,5)
    for ji in range(i*3,i*3+3):
        arr[ji,i] = val
    a_rand_row = np.random.randint(i*3,i*3+3)
    arr[a_rand_row,i] = np.nan

    comb[i*3:i*3+3] = val
    comb[a_rand_row] = val

init_cols = ["col1","col2","col3"]
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=init_cols)
df["comb"] = comb

### iterate over columns and set comb to nan if column is nan
for col in init_cols:
    df["comb"][df[col].isna()] = np.nan
```